# how to position one image on top of another?

Tags: julia

I'd like to occlude the pixels of an image in specific locations. Let's say from row 300:422 and columns 522:741. And let's say my code is this:

```
using Images
        
add = "http://wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/ship-image-3.jpeg"
img =  load(download(add))
        
occlude =   RMat = rand(RGB,100,250);
rowi = size(RMat,1)
coli = size(RMat,2)
        
        
for i in 1:rowi, j in 1:coli
    img[i,j] = RMat[i, j]
end
```

However, this changes the position in image that are correspond to pixel 1:size_of_Rmat. Is there an automatic way to randomly select a regions and put a `RMat` on top of `img`

Comment: adding offset to destination pixel might work: `img[i + 300,j + 522] = RMat[i, j]`

Answer (score 3):

You can broadcast-assign to the region where you want to position the new image.

```
julia> function occluderegion!(img, rowrange, colrange)
         occlude = rand(RGB, length(rowrange), length(colrange))
         img[rowrange, colrange] .= occlude
       end
occluderegion! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> occluderegion!(img, 300:422, 522:741);
```